# how to toggle replies, show and hide replies. And by default they should be hidden.

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have this commenting system that works fine
issue is when I refresh the page, replies are not folded. I have to click button to fold them

So to be as clear as possible, if there's comment A, and then under that comment A I want to have "view all x replies" button that's folded. if that button is clicked all the replies need to be shown.

So here's what I did.

```
<div class="wholeReply">
    <a href='#' class='replies'>           
      {{comment.comment_count}} replies</a>
    <div class="got_replies">
    <ul>
    {% for child in comment.get_children %}
    <li>{{ child.get_comment }} 
    <small><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' post.moderator.username %}">{{ child.user.user }}</a></small>


    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

$('.replies').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".got_replies").fadeToggle();  // $(".reply_comment").fadeToggle();
})
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).next(".got_replies").fadeToggle();` try this

Comment: @guradio thank you this fixes part of it but they are still unfolded when I refresh the page

Comment: have this code `$(".got_replies").fadeToggle();` out side of click event

Comment: @guradio that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @guradio actually that worked thank you very much is it possible to do "show replies" when they are  folded and "hide replies" when they are not folded with javascript?

Comment: yes do a condition to check if nearest reply is has display block then do the change in text accordingly. i will add this to answer so that you can accept it to lessen unanswered OP in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).next(".got_replies").fadeToggle();
```

To target the correct `reply` to toggle

```
$(".got_replies").fadeToggle();
```

To hide the reply on load

Comment: thanks can you show me how I can do that condition check to replace what I have with show/hide replies?